# How to access first row of array and then access key and element from it

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am working on WordPress + PHP, and I've used WordPress's get_results with OBJECT_K parameter, which returns array.

The output architecture somehow look like something like this (my guess):

```
UPDATED ARCHITECTURE -> var_export result

Array
(
    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [wp_reference_id] => 6
            [payer_email] => sb-epwcu1215095@personal.example.com
            [payer_first_name] => John
            [payer_last_name] => Doe
            [payer_address_street] => Level 01
            [payer_address_city] => Petaling Jaya
            [payer_address_state] => Selangor
            [payer_address_zip] => 47800
            [payer_country] => Malaysia
            [item_name] => Course 1
            [item_price] => 5.50
            [paypal_trans_id] => 43D048656J246002J
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [wp_reference_id] => 9
            [payer_email] => buyer@paypalsandbox.com
            [payer_first_name] => John
            [payer_last_name] => Smith
            [payer_address_street] => 123 any street
            [payer_address_city] => San Jose
            [payer_address_state] => CA
            [payer_address_zip] => 95131
            [payer_country] => United States
            [item_name] => something
            [item_price] => 12.34
            [paypal_trans_id] => 141020571
        )

)
```

I am wondering how do I only uses currentProducts's first row, in Python we can do something like currentProducts[0] and it returns the first row.

I've tried to foreach it with code

```
foreach ( $currentProducts as $page )
{
    echo '<script>console.log('.$page->wp_reference_id.')</script>';

}
```

which returns

```
6
9
```

and I am looking for something similar to but not luck.

```
$currentProducts[0]->wp_reference_id
$currentProducts[0]->wp_payment_id
```

Comment: Rather than guessing the structure, try something like `var_export($currentProducts);` to see what it contains.

Comment: show us the value of `var_export($currentProducts);` so that you will get a concrete answer rather then every-one guessing and giving suggestions meaninglessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply simple `foreach()` loop and get corresponding value

```
foreach($currentProducts as $currentProduct){
   echo '<script>console.log('.$currentProduct->wp_reference_id.')</script>';;
}
```

to get the first array data do `current()`

```
$firstArray = current( (Array)$currentProducts );
```

Sample output:- https://3v4l.org/97it2

Comment: @anant-singh-alive-to-die Exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

Comment: @SamLee glad to help you :):) happy coding...:)